# asyncio.run() closes the MainThread event loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

[`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) seems to close the MainThread event loop on Windows. For example:

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop()
<ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop().is_running()
False
```

I can successfully call the event loop with no `RuntimeError`.

Now let's run an async function.

```
>>> async def async_print():
...     await asyncio.sleep(1)
...     print('done sleeping')

>>> asyncio.run(async_print())
```

If we try to get the event loop, as we did earlier, we get the below error:

```
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop().is_running()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.
```

What is causing the RuntimeError now?

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run): This function always creates a new event loop and closes it at the end.

Comment: so why is the first one lost?

Comment: Because when [`run` sets the new event loop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ea46579067fd2d4e164d6605719ffec690c4d621/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L41), the [previous event loop is replaced](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ea46579067fd2d4e164d6605719ffec690c4d621/Lib/asyncio/events.py#L665).

Comment: @dirn I've never quite understood _why_ `run()` does that, though. It's not like it couldn't remember the previous event loop and just restore it instead of setting it to None and borking further use of `get_event_loop()` in that thread.

Comment: @user4815162342 you could do it with a custom policy that maintained a stack of loops

Comment: @dirn Sure, or you could just remember and set the old loop yourself. What I'm wondering about is the rationale for the default behavior of `asyncio.run()` - why does it clean up after itself by setting the `None` for current loop instead of restoring the old one, which seems like the logical thing to do.

Comment: @user4815162342 isn’t that the whole point of having policies? The default one discards the previous loop. If you need it, use a policy that keeps it.

Comment: @dirn I think policies are more about how to create event loops - for example, the proactor policy on Windows, or the uvloop policy for uvloop, or a glib event loop policy for the glib event loop, etc. The behavior of `asyncio.run` with regards to restoring the previous loop is orthogonal to all these and thus (IMHO) to the policies themselves. And even if policy were the intended mechanism to do it, it still wouldn't explain the reasoning behind the _default_ behavior of `asyncio.run()`, which is what I was wondering about in the original comment.

Comment: @user4815162342 policies also include behavior for setting the loop, but I guess they don’t have a mechanism for what to do after you’re done with the loop, so there’s be no automatic restoration.